# ssh key administration for many users, servers

Tags: server, administration, ssh

My company has some remote Ubuntu servers. The access to these servers is controlled by ssh keys. Managing these keys is quite a pain, especially when an employee leaves or joins the company.

Is there a good solution for central key management on Ubuntu?

Adam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Landscape

[Canonical's Landscape](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape/systems-management) makes it very easy to manage many machines at once.

You could just have a centralised key store and, on demand, push out changes to every machine's known_hosts file.

### Rsync

Alternatively, if you don't want to use Landscape, how about simply [synchronising the known_hosts via rsync](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=15082)? I'm not all that familiar with all this enterprisy business, but it should work very well.

Assuming the company's computers get shut down every night, i would do this:

- Have on some server a centralised known_hosts file that you manage manually.
- write a very simple program that, at boot time, tries to fetch that file and replace the current one
- on the administrative side, test all changed to the master-file before pushing it out, which you do by just replacing the one all the clients try to access.

you could use [RCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System), an old sysadmin's favourite, to manage different versions of your master-file.

Note that many sysadmins will tell you that *centralising things* is a security risk, and generally not a great idea.

### LDAP

Now, I'm not a sysadmin (and therefore not to be trusted on this matter). You really should ask this question on [**serverfault**](https://serverfault.com/)

LDAP seems to come up there quite a lot. Here's a bit information about fetching [SSH Public Keys from LDAP](http://blog.fupps.com/2006/03/02/ssh-public-keys-from-ldap/), and here's [some more](http://www.meta.net.nz/~daniel/blog/2006/04/07/ssh-ldap-public-key-lpk/).

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/180998/how-to-automatically-create-user-accounts-ssh-ldap) might also be of interest to you.

I hope this is helpful. As you've discovered yourself, managing ssh access in large setups really is quite complicated.

Comment: Look into setting LDAP, and mount the user's $HOME via NFS.  When the user leaves the company, delete his LDAP account and you're done. (user needs to exist before verifying ssh key)

Comment: I think he meant authorized_keys not known_hosts, though both are very important.

Comment: Made it community wiki, because - as I said - I'm not a sysadmin. Edit this answer to make it better.

Comment: How do you do this with Landscape? I don't see the option.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use certification authorities and revoke markers in the "known hosts" file.  Another option is probably to use some "enterprise" PAM authentication method instead.

Comment: A link would be extremely useful.